# dynamodb - add vector to field

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

In one of my tables in dynamodb have a field that contains a long vector of numbers. I would like to perform a vector addition to that field with another vector of numbers. Will this operation be valid? (I'm using boto with python)

```
UpdateExpression = "ADD my_vector_field :v",
ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ':v': [3, 8, 4, 5, ...]
}
```

Or, will I have no choice but do this:

```
UpdateExpression = "ADD my_vector_field[0], my_vector_field[1],... :v0, :v1,...",
ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ':v0': 3,
    ':v1': 8,
     .
     .
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I guess that by "vector" you refer to the [DynamoDB data type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) NS (Number Set). The `ADD` operation is working on sets and numbers but sadly not in the way you would expect it in your example:

- If you add a number to another number they are mathematically added
- If you add a element to a set it is appended

Adding a set to a set is not possible. In your case you can add items with data type N to NS or N, but not NS to NS.

You can either choose your second approach or do the computations on your machine and then update the entire set with `SET`.